# How to copy an object from anarray, edit it and push it back as new object to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to copy an object from a given array, change some of the values and push it back to the array as new value.

```
//array:
entries[
{id: "1234", credit: "2000", debit: "3000"},
{id: "1235", credit: "2000", debit: "3000"},
{id: "1236", credit: "2000", debit: "3000"}
]
```

What I did is the following:
I filtered the array for searching the object.

```
result = entries.filter(entry => entry.id == id);
```

Say, I got the object with id 1235 in an array result back as first value. The object is here: `result[0]`.

**Now, I need a copy from exact this array, switch the credit and debit values and push it back to the entries-array as new item.**

I tried this so far, but this does not work:

```
Object.assign(newObj, oldObj);
newObj.debit = result[0].credit;
newObj.credit = result[0].debit;
newObj.id = getNewEntryId(data); // here I get an new id which is free - works fine so far
entries.push(newObj);
```

The new and the old objects are getting changed. I think assign makes not a copy, only a link. Which function should I choose? Or how is this problem solved normally?

Comment: Object.create() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newObject = Object.assign({}, entries.filter(entry => entry.id == id));
newObject.id = ...;
entries.push(newObject);
```

should do the trick :)

If you have an object with methods use `Object.create` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use lodash with deepClone function, which recursively creates full copy.

Comment: I am in the phase of learning js and want to code with pure js.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newObj = {
    ...oldObj,
    id: oldObj.id,
    debit: oldObj.credit,
    credit: oldObj.debit
};
entries.push(newObj);
```

Comment: Thank you. With your solution I would loose additional key/value pairs if there are any (which could be in later versions).

Comment: then just spread the oldObject inside newObj and override properties you want to.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.